# Why am I unable to deploy a xamarin.ios app to my device?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, csproj

I am working on an iOS application (using Visual Studio on Windows 10 running in Parallels on macOS X) and I have setup a configuration used for `Ad-hoc` deployment. Somehow, I am unable to deploy the application to my iOS device: the deploy menu item is simply not there.

As recommended in different answers from different websites, the solution usually consists in checking the Deploy option in the Configuration Manager. However, I am faced with the following dialog box:

[image: Configuration Manager]

The Deploy option is disabled.

As shown below, I can see that my Visual Studio instance is successfully connected to the iOS agent and that my phone is visible:

[image: Setup]

I looked into the `Ad-hoc` configuration part from the iOS `csproj` file but I did not see anything obvious that would allow the option to be enabled:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Ad-Hoc|iPhone' ">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\iPhone\Ad-Hoc</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>False</ConsolePause>
    <MtouchArch>ARM64</MtouchArch>
    <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
    <BuildIpa>false</BuildIpa>
    <CodesignProvision>Demo (Ad-hoc)</CodesignProvision>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution: Christophe --- (X---)</CodesignKey>
    <MtouchExtraArgs>-v -v -v -v --linkskip=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
        --linkskip=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational --linkskip=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
        --linkskip=Remotion.Linq --linkskip=Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core
        --linkskip=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core
        --linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
        --linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection --linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
        --linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging --linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions
        --linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory --linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.Options
        --linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives --linkskip=System.Reflection --linkskip=System.Reflection.Primitives
        --linkskip=System.Linq --linkskip=System.Linq.Expressions --linkskip=System.Linq.Queryable</MtouchExtraArgs>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Question**

Why is the Deploy option disabled and is it possible to enabled it?

Comment: what happens when you click the green triangle?

Comment: It says that Visual Studio can't start the debugger because Debugging is not enabled for this configuration (as expected).

Comment: Could your project run on simulator?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT The project can indeed run on a simulator; this is actually what I am using when developing & debugging the application (Debug|iPhoneSimulator). However it is **not** working in the configuration (Ad-hoc|iPhone) as the simulator is not part of the provisioned devices. And, on top on that, I can't deploy it either (Ad-hoc|iPhoneSimulator)..

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Deploy checkboxes disabled in Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/deploy-checkboxes)

Since Xamarin 3.5, Xamarin.iOS projects deployed automatically whenever you press the Start toolbar button or pick the Debug > Start Debugging menu item. You will still need to set the desired Xamarin.iOS app project as the StartUp Project before running either of those commands.